# Multiple linked libraries, how to manage same version of same dependencies?

Tags: ios, swift, carthage, cocoa-touch

I've not been successful in Googling a solution to this.

- We are using Carthage to manage dependencies.
- We have a Cocoa Touch framework for our domain objects, let's call it `DomainKit`.
- We have a Cocoa Touch framework for our adapters, let's call it `AdapterKit`.

`DomainKit` is dependent on `RxSwift`.
`AdapterKit` is dependent on `RxSwift` and `Realm`.

Our app is dependent on `DomainKit` and `AdapterKit`.
The app is the one copying the frameworks using Carthage.

The `Cartfile.resolved` files for all of the above look like this:

```
DomainKit
    github "ReactiveX/RxSwift" "3.4.0"

AdapterKit
    github "ReactiveX/RxSwift" "3.4.1"
    github "[redacted]/ios-DomainKit" "0.0.7"
    github "realm/realm-cocoa" "v2.7.0"

App
    github "ReactiveX/RxSwift" "3.4.1"
    github "[redacted]/ios-AdapterKit" "0.0.5"
    github "[redacted]/ios-DomainKit" "0.0.7"
    github "realm/realm-cocoa" "v2.6.2"
```

The disconnect in the versions of `RxSwift` and `Realm` are causing a crash in the application.

So the question is... have any of you have encountered this problem and if you did, how did you solve the problem?

Comment: Is updating all frameworks to use the same versions of mentioned dependencies out of the question?

Comment: Definitely not out of the question. We do this regularly. I suppose I'm looking for a solution where I can somewhat automate this process without having to manually keep on top of this.

Comment: At this point, I'm contemplating having some kind of Ruby script or Fastlane script pull versions from some gist or repo to make sure all is compatible. It just seems like a hack solution. Figured I'd ask if there was something better than this out there...

Comment: Well, after modularizing our app we manually synchronize about 20 in-house pods, and some outside ones ;) If you do it regularly, it isn't that much of a trouble.

Comment: It happened once and caused a crash during a demo, ha! So I'm trying to find a fool proof solution. I'm a utopian.

Comment: Well, the parsing part of `Podfile` or `Cartfile` and figuring out the appropriate version is quite easy. The hard part are the code changes in the dependencies - you can't be sure if they are backwards compatible. If not, then you will still have to look at the code and update it.